# How to install gdal_merge to run with osgeo?

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I recently installed OSGEO (http://download.osgeo.org/) which included python and gdal. I just realised however that there are many gdal libraries that were not included in this package  for example gdal_merge. How can I install them into the osgeo environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this link:

[gdal_merge.py](https://github.com/omniscale/gbi-client/blob/master/app/geobox/lib/gdal_merge.py)

Copy everything and save the script as gdal_merge.py.

Put the gdal_merge.py to the your gdal libraries directory(osgeo directory).

Comment: Great, so how do we access it?

Comment: @colllin click the 'Raw' button on the github page, it will take you here..

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geobox-infrastructure/gbi-client/master/app/geobox/lib/gdal_merge.py

Comment: @colllin   If I am using anaconda3, where exactly I should paste this file?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, in the **OSGeo4W** setup program, `gdal_merge.py` and the other GDAL Python scripts are included in the **gdal-python** package in the **Libs** Category.

When installed, the Python scripts are copied to the `bin` subdirectory within the OSGeo4W installation directory along with batch files to launch the Python scripts. (For example, `gdal_merge.bat`).

Once installed, the GDAL Python scripts can be executed from the **OSGeo4W Shell** which is available from the Windows Start Menu.